Do something you can't do in Brainfuck
Goal
Do some action (like delete a file, connect to a server, …) that you can not do in standard Brainfuck.
What
As you know, all calculations you can do in almost any programming language you can also do in standard Brainfuck.
However, since standard Brainfuck can't do most syscalls, there are many things that are impossible to do in Brainfuck. Your goal is to do anything that is impossible in Brainfuck.
Rules
Do something that is not possible with a valid program in standard Brainfuck.
With standard Brainfuck i mean:

It only uses the 8 Brainfuck instructions ([]+-<>.,).
All cells start with the value 0.
The output/input is not interpreted/generated in a special way to do any other actions (except what standard Unix terminals may do).
There are no unexpected features in the Brainfuck implementation, accessible from the Brainfuck code.
Assume that there are no implementations Bugs.
The implementation may or may not request more memory from the OS when more cells / higher values are used.
The implementation could have any execution speed.
The implementation may or may not halt when a negative cell index or a cell index that is out of bounds (in case the implementation has a limited amount of cells) is reached and may or may not generates an error with a message and/or exit with a different exit code.
The implementation can have any number of bits peer cell (from 1 to virtually infinite).
The implementation may or may not run on a UNIX terminal, where you can set colours, bold or italic letter, clear the screen and jump with the cursor just by sending special sequences.

Anything on this list counts as impossible with any standard Brainfuck implementation. Write a program that does at least one from the following  this list or something else that is impossible in standard Brainfuck:

Create, delete or move a File**.
Open a file that wasn't opened before (i.e. not stdout, stderr nor stdin).
Get/display the current time.
Shutdown, restart, … the system (when your program isn't the only program).
Change the current working directory.
Get/display command-line arguments.
Do anything that requires the internet.
Fork/start or kill a process (other than the program's own process).
Get random numbers from a external (i.e. not from a PRNG with a fixed seed nor a seed from the input) source.
Wait on user input with a timeout.
Send a signal to a different process.
Change its own command line.
Write a specific message to stdout AND a specific message to stderr. (By specific, i mean a message that is completely controlled by the code and not the implementation).
Change the baud rate on a serial port.
Mount, unmount, format, defragment, eject … a drive/partition.
Enable/disable a network connection.
Catch and react to a signal (other than the standard action).
Play a sound other than the \a/Bell-Character.
Open or close a Windows (Except closing the own terminal).
Getting / display info about the underlining OS or Hardware (except for the size of a Byte)
…

**It is theoretically possible to write a Brainfuck program that emulates a shell where you can create and delete files within, but that file would only exist in RAM inside the Brainfuck program, so it is not the same.
Things that are, at least theoretically, possible in Brainfuck and don't count:



What
Explanation
Example




Do calculations
Brainfuck is turing complete
-


Show graphics
A Brainfuck program can use coloured  text or different Letter to display the pixels of an image.
Mandelbrot, Coloroutput


Show animations
Outputing multiple images can create an animation
BadApple


Delay/Wait a short time
Some interpreters have a fixed clock rate and you can calculate a delay based on the number of executed instructions.
-


Exit with EXIT_SUCCESS or EXIT_FAILURE
Some interpreters will exit with EXIT_FAILURE when a negative cell is reached.
Codegolf Answer


Write to stdout and a generic error message to stderr.
Brainfuck can write to stdout. Accessing a negative cell index may cause some interpreter do display an error message



Use a certain amount of RAM or request more memory from the OS
Some implementations request more RAM when more cells are used
-


Read or write from a single already opened file.
On Unix, stdin and stdout can be almost any file, which can be set before the  Process starts. This is standard and an expected feature of the OS/shell.



Display the size of a Byte
A Brainfuck program could detect the size of a single cell (which i count as a Byte) and display it
-


Write to stdout and a standard error message to stderr
Some implementations write to stdout normally but display a error message when they reach a error condition, such as reaching a cell with negative index
Online interpreter with separate error Output.



Shortest code wins.
Example
An ungolfed example in Python:
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))


What does "get random numbers from an external source" mean? random.random()?

@Tbw It means a real random number generator, not a PRNG, which is just an algorithm and can be implemented in BF.

@mbomb007 ...unless the PRNG implementation uses the system time (or something else unavailable to BF) as a seed perhaps?

Does writing to stderr count (e.g. Python, 1 byte - / - Try it online)?

This seems very broad. I'm holding off on closing this due to my mod hammer, but currently the distinction between what brainfuck can and can't do depends on the implementation, due to the fact it's Turing complete. I'd suggest choosing a specific implementation that is representative enough of brainfuck so that people can objectively compare between their answers and brainfuck

Related

I don't really understand your reasoning - stderr and stout are different and a user of a program can tell which was written to if they want, so why does being able to do stuff outside of the BF program that can make it look like it's doing the same thing as the non-BF program mean it counts as doing the same thing?

Here’s an example of why it’s implementation-dependent: the following Bash program: "", 0 bytes, is a test for whether /usr/lib/libc.so exists or not, with output via exit code. At least, you can specify exactly what OS environment bash needs to run in for this to work. But does the same 0  byte trick work in Brainfuck? Depends on whether the Brainfuck interpreter is linked to libc or not! This also needs to be defined

@pxeger Yes, it is implementations defined. However, i disagree on your example, the interpreter does not run then it isn't something your brainfuck program is doing. But lets talk about an interpreter that just interprets regular brainfuck (without any special functions, nor any special data on the tape), what can non of them do?

@Jonathan Allan I updated the question. The rule of the question was: Writing to a single file (doesn't matter if it is stdout, stderr or something else) doesn't count. Why: Brainfuck writtes to an output stream, and in most interpreter it is very easy to set what that output is writing to, it is an expected feature of many implementations. However, writing to 2 files (for example, stdout and stderr) counts. If you can create better rules, you can make a new and better challenge/question (especially since this question is closed).

Reopen vote cast, thanks for the update!

Bash, 2 bytes
>_

Try it online!
Create a file named '_' in the current directory.

How about w? Shorter but it needs the binary w, >_ is builtin.

Jelly, 0 bytes
A full program that prints 0 unless provided an argument in which case it prints* the Jellification** of that argument evaluated as Python code if possible or the raw argument as a string if not. (Satisfies the requirements since Brainfuck can only read from stdin, not from command line arguments).
Try it online!
* an empty lists prints as nothing; a mixed list (characters and numbers) smashes its element's representations together, a singleton list prints its element.
** None becomes an empty list; complex numbers with no imaginary part become floats; dictionaries become a list of their keys if all keys are strings; probably other things may happen in other exceptional cases

PARI/GP, 2 bytes
\s
Attempt This Online!
\s prints the state of the PARI stack and heap, which is non-deterministic.
Example output:
 Top : 7fadf82bd000   Bottom : 7fadf7b1be00   Current stack : 7fadf82bcfb8
 Used :                         9  long words  (0 K)
 Available :                    999991  long words  (7808 K)
 Occupation of the PARI stack :   0.00 percent
 1 objects on heap occupy 9 long words

 10 variable names used (10 user + 0 private) out of 65535

Copied from my answer to another challenge.

Ruby, 3 bytes
Prints the command-line arguments.
p$*

Attempt This Online!

Python 3, 11 bytes
open(*'ww')

Create a file called w in the current directory.

Javascript, 7 bytes


alert()



Window is the point

Funge-98, 4 bytes
6y,@

Try it online!
Outputs the operating system's path separator (/ for POSIX, \ for Windows).

Batch, 2 bytes
hh

Launches HTML help (which displays its own window).

@JonathanAllan Can BF print to stderr?

@JonathanAllan Actually of the three, only fc prints to stderr, so the other two aren't acceptable. (hh opens a separate window, which BF definitely can't do.)

Apparently, "Read or write from a single file." in the "don't count" list rules this out for reasons I don't fully comprehend

@JonathanAllan Looks like I'll have to stick with hh then...

APL+WIN, 3 bytes
Outputs the current time to the nearest msec.
⎕ts

Try it online! Thang to Dyalog Classic

Python 2, 11 bytes
print id(0)

This program outputs the address of the object 0 in memory.
Run it here

Hmm, what would BF be expected to output? (Python instantiates that memory, so I think it may be a bit of a -chicken- python and egg; perhaps the empty output is "correct" for a BF program?)

@JonathanAllan This is effectively an rng.

Outputting to stderr isn't possible in BF, so 1/0 for three?

@WheatWizard ah yes, that would help in the description :) (EDIT: and I've used this property myself before! >.<)

...or maybe just / as that raises a SyntaxError and pipes its message to stderr.

I don't see how this is impossible to do in Brainfuck. Well, the argument you could make is that ASLR generates a random address and you use it as random generator from a external source.

C++, 46 bytes
#include<ios>
main(){freopen("x","w",stdout);}

Creates a file called 'x' in the current directory (if x does not exist). I think this still counts.
Try it online!

You don't need the #include for fopen(). How about system("w");?

@12431234123412341234123 Thanks! I'll have a look into how to do that.

Is it valid to return the number of arguments as an exit code? If so, 22 bytes are enough

QBasic, 6 3 bytes
CLS

Clears the screen.
Try it at Archive.org!
If it turns out there is technically some way to do this in BF (e.g. by outputting a bunch of newlines), then here's a 5-byte solution:
FILES

Outputs the contents of the current working directory.

Nice idea. However, in many terminals there is \033c or \033[2J which clears the screen. Is this something different?

Truthfully, I don't know enough about DOS to answer that question. :P That's why I included the alternate solution.

The challenge states: With standard Brainfuck i mean: [...] The implementation may or may not run on a UNIX terminal, where you can set colours, bold or italic letter, clear the screen and jump with the cursor just by sending special sequences.. So the 3 bytes answer is not valid here.

Trivial answers that output command-line arguments
Many languages can easily read command-line args:
Pip, 1 byte
a

Outputs the first command-line argument. Attempt This Online!

I think this CW should be broadened to include obvious RNG/system time answers

Google Sheets / Excel, 6 bytes
=NOW()

Returns the current date and time.

JavaScript (Node.js), 9 bytes
_=>Date()

Try it online!

Wrong. Run this Python program, paste the output at this BF interpreter, select the Cell size of "32", and click run. That was for your 8-byte program. Still it can output any Unicode character.

For BF interpreters where the output is automatically decoded as UTF-8, such as TIO, we can make use of the fact that ā is encoded as 0xC4 0x81, and write those two numbers separately: Try it online!
